# Domain, Range, and Relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, relations

> Show that if R is a relation, then $\cup\cup R =(\operatorname{dom}R)\cup(\operatorname{ran}R)$.

- First, I don't know what $\cup\cup R$ means where $R$ is a relation.
- I want to know what is the membership relation on $R$.

Please help me.

Answer (score 6):

When we say that $R$ is a relation then we say that $R$ is a set (or class) of ordered pairs. In the usual contexts of modern set theory, this means that the elements of $R$ are sets of the form $\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$, and that $a$ is in $\text{dom} R$ and $b\in\text{rng} R$.

When we write $\bigcup A$ we mean $\{u\mid\exists v\in A. u\in v\}$, that is $\bigcup_{B\in A} B$.

So $\bigcup R$ would be all the sets $\{a\}$ and $\{a,b\}$, in a big collection, and $\bigcup\bigcup R$ would be simply those $a$'s and $b$'s.

I hope this clears out the idea, and I am leaving you to write the details.

Comment: THANK YOU. BUT, CAN YOU TELL ME WHAT THE MEMBERSHIP RELATION ON R IS?

Comment: CAN YOU REPEAT THAT WITHOUT PRESSING THE SHIFT KEY WHILE TYPING?

Comment: Can you tell me what the membership relation on R is?

Comment: @user67458: $R$ is a set. It's the same membership relation as any other set.

Comment: Actually, I don't know What the membership relation on a set is. Can you explain it please?

Comment: I don't understand the question. At all. You have a set $X$, and it may have elements (which, in set theory are also sets). $a$ is an element of $X$ if and only if $a\in X$. That's all.

Comment: You mean..If R is the membership relation on the set P3 where 3={0,1,2},   ({0,1},{1}) is in R and ({0,1},{2}) is not in R?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly: If $R$ is the membership relation on a set $P$ then $\langle x,y\rangle\in R$ if and only if $x,y\in P$ and $x\in y$.

Comment: oh, I can understand now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

First of all, recall the most usual (set-theoretic) definition of a relation:

> A **(binary) relation** $R$ on $X$ is a subset of $X \times X$

Alternative accounts do not insist both factors are the same (i.e. allow $R \subseteq X \times Y$). In either case, $R$ is a set of ordered pairs.

Now the set-theoretic definition (due to Kuratowski) of an ordered pair $(x,y)$ is the set $\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$. The definition of union implies that we have:

$$\cup\cup R = \cup \{z \in (x,y): (x,y) \in R\}$$

By the definition of $(x,y)$ above, we see that $z \in (x,y)$ iff $z = x$ or $z = y$. Can you take it from here?